# Maximum size of a cube in which a cube is mapped by linear transformation in Euclidean space

Tags: analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Suppose $L:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ where $L$ is a linear transformation and $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Then it is automatic that
$$
\|L(x)-L(x')\| \leq M \| x-x'\|
$$
for $x, x' \in E$ and some $M>0$. A text that I am reading (Elias and Shakarchi) says that a cube of side $l$ will mapped into a cube of side at most $2 \sqrt{d} M l$. I understand all factors (take the diagonal of the original cube) but do not understand where the 2 is coming from. Kindly point out what I am missing. This assertion is given in Exercise 8 of Chapter 1 in Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis (Book III). In my view, the bound should be $\sqrt{d/2} M l$.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing an orthonormal basis we get $$L(x)-L(y)=L(t_1e_1+…+t_ne_n)-L(s_1e_1+…+s_ne_n)=$$$$(t_1-s_1)L(e_1)+…+(t_n-s_n)L(e_n)=$$$$<x-y,e_1L(e_1)+…e_nL(e_n)>.$$ Then use cauchy-schwarz. Then check where the unit cube gets mapped. Every cube can then be streched from the unit cube.